# How to restrict mailbox access for office 365 app

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, office365, imap

I'm trying to figure out how to restrict which mailbox an application can access.

I have followed this guide and used app-only authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

According to the documentation i have to set the '**full_access_as_app**' permission.
However the info text states:
"Allows the app to have full access via Exchange Web Services to **all mailboxes** without a signed-in user."

I'm able to read mailboxes but i would like to restrict which mailbox my application can access.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

My code:

```
   static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appId"])
            .WithClientSecret(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["clientSecret"])
            .WithTenantId(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["tenantId"])
            .Build();

        var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

        try
        {
            var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService
            {
                Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"),
                Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken),
                ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, "emailaddress@domain.com")
            };

            var mailbox = new Mailbox("emailaddress@domain.com");
            var folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, mailbox);

            var inbox = Folder.Bind(ewsClient, folderId);

            if (inbox != null)
            {
                FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(new ItemView(100));

                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Subject);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (MsalException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex}");
        }

        if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is basically a [support question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746/fnord), not a programming question, and those are offtopic. You have to ask Microsoft how to configure that Outlook account.

Comment: @arnt, I agree this is not purely a programming question but it is a question about how to use the API of Office365 (Exchange Online). It's a Programming Interface, so it's not jus a matter of " ask Microsoft how to configure that Outlook account" either. 

Let's see if someone has worked with this API before and understands how it works or can point him in the right direction.

The link you added to the 'support question' even says: "We're here to help you with your challenges writing code. If that code involves some company's API, fine. We're more than happy to help you with that. "

Comment: @roberth FYI, I have, and do understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow [Scoping application permissions to specific Exchange Online mailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access).

Although this document is under Microsoft Graph, it should also apply to the `https://outlook.office365.com` module because this setting is for app registration and O365 mailbox.

You need to create an application access policy which sets the `-AccessRight RestrictAccess`.

And then test the newly created application access policy which restricts access to the user `user1@contoso.com`.

```
Test-ApplicationAccessPolicy -Identity user1@contoso.com -AppId e7e4dbfc-046-4074-9b3b-2ae8f144f59b
```